# 'npm run eject' error 'missing script: eject' in react

Tags: reactjs

I use npm create-react-app
to create a new app
This is my
package.json file

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

This is the error code:

```
npm run eject
npm ERR! missing script: eject

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\acmilanyjguo\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-08-28T04_26_15_274Z-debug.log
```

This is the log file:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'eject'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.5
3 info using node@v12.18.2
4 verbose config Skipping project config: C:\Users\acmilanyjguo/.npmrc. (matches userconfig)
5 verbose stack Error: missing script: eject
```

I can't run eject, couldn't find the reason. I'd like to know the reason, thanks.

Comment: Could you clarify whether the other npm commands are working for you? `npm run start`, etc

Comment: Can you make sure that you are running `npm run eject` in the same directory as your `package.json` file?

Comment: I find the reason: I can't run `npm run start` After solving the problem, I can run eject now.

Comment: @MaomaoYi How did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
You must check where is your build.

If it is on your **frontend** then `cd frontend` and hint `npm run eject`
If it is in your **backend** then in the `backend` and hint `npm run eject`

for me, the build was in the **frontend** package and I hint in the backend because that it was not working

Comment: Could you give us examples of paths for frontend/backend for easier locating? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal windows and
Just run:

> npm i -g react-scripts